# Unable to upload an image file to PUBLISHED node.acs application

Tags: node.js, file-upload, image-uploading

I am trying to build a front end to my ACS ( Appcelerator Cloud Service) database. As a part of the admin front end, users will upload images and I am using Photos object to save them. I am using following code to upload the photos to cloud db and it works very well on my local system/PC.

```
var data = {
session_id:req.session.session_id,
    photo: req.files.photo_file
};
data['photo_sizes[medium_500]'] = '500x333';
data['photo_sync_sizes[]'] = 'medium_500';

ACS.Photos.create(data, function(e) {
    if(e.success && e.success === true){
      // Update custom object with this photo
      ACS.Objects.update({
        session_id:req.session.session_id,
        classname:objname,
        id:objid,
        fields: {
            photo_id:e.photos[0].id,
            photo_url:e.photos[0].urls.medium_500
        }
      },function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                // console.log('Updated successfully:' + JSON.stringify(data));
                res.send(data);
            }else {
                console.log('Error:\n' +
                ((data.error && data.message) || JSON.stringify(data)));
            }
        }
      );
      //res.send(data);
    }else{
      logger.debug('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
      req.session.flash = {msg:e.message, r:0};
      res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

What's happening here is, a mutipart HTML form is uploading the file. That file is read on server and passed to the ACS.Photos.create call. However, when I publish the app to the cloud, it gives following error and application crashes.
**[ERROR] [1233] Error: EACCES, open '/tmp/292fb15dcab44f58a315515bd9e70a8a'**

Looking at the error it's clear that, server is not able to access the /tmp directory.

Node.acs is built on top of Node.js, I saw several node.js examples using this approach. How this issue is handled when the application/website is published or goes live on a web server?

Thanks,

Niranjan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was indeed some file permission issue. Take a look at this post on the node.acs group.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-acs/XrRxBTtwiO4

The problem is now SOLVED !